# After update to Windows 10 there Clipboard is almost always full

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, microsoft-excel, clipboard

Recently my company updated the operating system from Windows 7 to Windows 10, and since then almost every time I'm trying to copy and paste even the smallest data into an Excel I'm getting a message that there is not enough memory.
And after pasting that data I'm closing the source document and getting a message that the clipboard is almost full and if I want to clean it up I need to close 
source document...
Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: It sounds like you have a third-party clipboard manager running in the background.  Your local network Administrator will have to help you in solving this particular problem.  The reason it is happening is something is keeping the data in the clipboard and Excel is picking up on that data.

Comment: Did this issue only occur when you use Excel?

Answer (score 1):

When you collect too many items on your clipboard, you might get an error that says your clipboard is full. Here’s how to empty the clipboard.

To delete all clips or an individual clip, first open the Clipboard task pane.

1. On the **Home** tab, in the **Clipboard** group, click the **Clipboard** dialog box launcher.

[image]

2. The **Clipboard** task pane appears on the left side of your spreadsheet and shows all clips in the clipboard.

[image]

3. To clear the entire clipboard, click the **Clear All** button.

[image]

4. To delete an individual clip, hover next to the clip, click the arrow to the right of the clip, and click **Delete**.

[image]

Comment: I did try this one too... And there is usually just that one file (clip?) that's about 200kb big.
I think that @Ramhound might be right, there must be something else messing up with the memory.

Comment: Did this error only occur when you copy and paste in the Excel or the whole computer?